# Conversão de endereço no Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Estou fazendo uma App para buscar endereços no Google Maps.

Existe alguma maneira de converter uma `String` em `Location`, para que eu possa pegar a longitude e latitude? Ou existe maneira melhor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a resposta (demorou mas encontrei!).

O Android possui uma classe chamada [Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html), que permite fazer essas conversões. É preciso também de dar a permissão de acesso a internet e GPS:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"
```

Answer (score 2):

**É em JAVASCRIPT?**

```
str = "12.12345 -15.12345";

x = str.split(" "); // para partir em 2 a string

lat = x[0];
lon = x[1];

latLon = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
```

latLon estará no formato aceito pelo app do google.
Quer uma dica? veja como está escrito o formato latLon:

```
alert(  JSON.stringify( latLon )  );
```

Comment: Não em Java mesmo.